# Find $K_1,K_2$ given $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{(x\cos x-\sin x)^2}{x^6} dx=\cdots$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

> If $$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{(x\cos x-\sin x)^2}{x^6} dx=\frac{1}{K_1}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x} dx+\frac{1}{K_2}\int_0^{\infty}\left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)^2 dx,$$ find $K_{1}$ and $K_{2}$.

---

First attempt:
I tried using expansions on both sides to see if the integrals can be equated by adjusting $K_1,K_2$

But the integral on the LHS of the equation has some terms with negative power, whereas the integral on the RHS of the equation has only positive powers, hence, this method is not suitable.

---

Second attempt: I used IBP ,and ended up with the following equation

$$-\frac{1}{5x^5}(x \cos x-\sin x)^2\bigg|_0^{\infty}
+\frac{1}{5}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{2}{x^5}(x \cos x-\sin x)(-x \sin x) dx$$

But I can't proceed further,

**NOTE**: This is from a book for JEE advanced. There are no closed forms of these integrals in the syllabus of JEE, but I know that $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x}=\frac{\pi}{2}$. I also know that it is proved by Fermat's method.

Comment: Try integrating by parts the other direction?  $\frac{x\cos x-\sin x}{x^2} = (\frac{\sin x}{x})'$

Comment: @RobertTheTutor I don't think it works..because of the square on $xcosx-sinx$

Answer (score 2):

Integrate by parts repeatedly

\begin{align}
& \int_0^{\infty}\frac{(x\cos x-\sin x)^2}{x^6} dx\\
=& -\frac15 \int_0^{\infty} (x\cos x-\sin x)^2 d(\frac1{x^5} )\\
=& -\frac1{15} \int_0^{\infty} (x\sin 2x+\cos 2x-1)d(\frac1{x^3} )\\
=& \frac1{30} \int_0^{\infty} (2x\cos 2x-\sin 2x)d(\frac1{x^2} )\\
= & \frac2{15} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin x}xdx \\
\end{align}

Comment: but what about the first part after applying byparts I mean the term $\frac{1}{5x^5}(x \cos x-\sin x)^2\bigg|_0^{\infty}$

Comment: @Learner - it is evaluated to zero at both ends

Comment: That term is zero... as $x\rightarrow\infty$ it clearly vanishes, and as $x\rightarrow 0^+$, you have $x\cos x - \sin x = x(1 - x^2/2 + O(x^4)) - (x - x^3/3! + O(x^5)) \sim -x^3/3$, so its square is $\sim x^6 / 9$, and so when divided by $x^5$ it still goes to zero.